# Implement sparse fieldset in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I'm using `rails-api` with serializers and I'm especially looking for an easy way to implement "sparse fieldset", that means I want my Rails API to render (json) only the fields I give in the parameter `fields`:

```
http://api.website.com/v1/ressource/id?fields=field1,field2
```

I know we can get `field1`, `field2` etc with `params[:field]` into the ressource controller, but I'm still not sure: the problem has to be fixed into the controller ? model ? serializer ?

I have seen few posts on this topic and no one is finally given a strong and universal response to this problem. How well-known Rails API are doing this ?

Thank you by advance for your explanations and advice.

Comment: Sorry, I actually realized my answer didn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually fields are limited in an api response through serializers.

- approach 1 : if your field values are dynamic
  In your controller , you can do something like this : say your resource corresponds to Resource

  ```
  fieldset = params[:fields].split(',')
  resource_id = params[:id]
  resource = Resource.where(id: resource_id).select([fieldset])
  render json: resource.first
  ```
- approach 2 : if you have fixed permutation of fields, you can use different serializers for each combination

  in your controller, instead of accepting fields, accept which serializer you want to use

  ```
  resource = Resource.find_by(id: resource_id)
  serializer = params[:serializer]
  render json: resource.first, serializer: serializer: Serializer1 if serializer == 'serializer1'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Using the master branch of ActiveModelSerializers, you can use the `fields` option of the JsonApi adapter, which does exactly what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know if that branch will be included in rails-api which comes, as announced, with Rails 5 ?